Combine pass in compositior Blender 4.2
Is there any way to combine passes in the compositor?
For example if I want to modify only the Glossy Direct pass and combine the result in the final image. How can I do that ?
The node Add (2 images) no longer exists on Blender 4.2.

There never was an Add node (or at least not anymore for a very very long time). It is the Mix Color node set to the blending mode Add. Just like there is no Add node for adding float values, it is the Math node set to Add.

It works the same way as in many previous versions.
You add direct and indirect passes and multiply the result by color pass for diffuse, glossy, transmission and volume passes add them together and add emission and environment passes, AO is not something realistic, so you can do whatever you want with it, but generally what you want with AO tends to be multiplication. See the documentation
Looks something like this:

You use Color Mix node like Gordon Brinkmann explained in the comment.

It makes sense to group some nodes and have it tidy when you actually work with it.
While working it might make sense to have some sort of sustainable system for organizing nodes, for example, personally, I work from left to right adding whatever I need along the path of all the passes. Could look something like this:


Thank you for your answer :)

Consider up-voting or accepting it as the answer if you find it useful.

Just a thought, I wonder if it wouldn't be nice to have an addon that can automatically generate that end node group and named reroutes from the passes you have on a render layer node.

Node Wrangler creates and names reroutes and you can shift-RMB-drag to insert them on many lines at once. Different purposes might also require different passes. For example, you might not need direct and indirect light passes and may want to combine them straight after render before compositing. Creating whatever nodes you need to combine the passes you use only takes a couple of minutes though and you can also save the group as an asset. It's quite alright as it is already. An add-on would add just a small bit of convenience, not sure if it's worth going through the trouble of writing it.
